# Error reading JToken from JsonReader in ASP.NET CORE 3.1 WebApi

Tags: asp.net-core, cloudinary

I'm using Cloudinary to upload the images in my ASP.NET CORE 3.1 application and when I call _cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams), it throws an exception as following:

```
    System.Exception: Failed to deserialize response with status code: Redirect  --->
             Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JToken from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.
at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ReadFrom(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings) 
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken
    .Parse(String json, JsonLoadSettings settings) at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Parse(String json)
     
    at CloudinaryDotNet.ApiShared.CreateResultFromString[T](String s, HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace
```

Following is the code of my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddPhotoForUser(int userId, [FromForm]PhotoForCreationDto photoForCreationDto)
{
    if (userId != int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value))
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }
var userFromRepo = await _repo.GetUser(userId);

var file = photoForCreationDto.File;
var uploadResult = new ImageUploadResult();

if (file.Length > 0)
{
    using(var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
    {
        var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
        {
            File = new FileDescription(file.Name, stream),
            Transformation = new Transformation().Width(500).Height(500).Crop("fill").Gravity("face")
        };

        uploadResult = _cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
    }
}

photoForCreationDto.Url = uploadResult.Uri.ToString();
photoForCreationDto.PublicId = uploadResult.PublicId;

var photo = _mapper.Map<Photo>(photoForCreationDto);

if (!userFromRepo.Photos.Any(u => u.IsMain))
{
    photo.IsMain = true;
}

userFromRepo.Photos.Add(photo);

if (await _repo.SaveAll())
{
    var photoToReturn = _mapper.Map<PhotoForReturnDto>(photo);

    return CreatedAtRoute("GetPhoto", new { userId = userId, id = photo.Id }, photoToReturn);
}

return BadRequest("Could not add the photo");
}
```

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue, but the error is Foribidden, only happens when i run the app from the cli, in the debugger everything goes fine.
https://github.com/cloudinary/CloudinaryDotNet/issues/223